# How to Sort alphanumeric strings in numpy matrix and list in Python?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list transformed from a dict with a 3-feature key, e.g.

```
{('consumer0', 'consumer0', 0): 0}
```

To sort the list, what I did is

```
    time = np.arange(1)
    agent = ['consumer0', 'consumer10', 'consumer11', 'consumer20',
             'consumer1', 'consumer2', 'consumer3', 'consumer4',
             'consumer5', 'consumer6', 'consumer7', 'consumer8',
             'consumer9']
    P_nm = {}
    for t in time:
        for p1 in agents:
            for p2 in agents:
                P_nm[p1, p2, t] = t

    P_nm = [(k, v) for k, v in P_nm.items()]
    P_nm.sort(key=lambda k: (k[0][2], k[0][0], k[0][1]))
```

I get a result like:

```
[(('consumer0', 'consumer0', 0), 0), 
 (('consumer0', 'consumer1', 0), 0), 
 (('consumer0', 'consumer10', 0), 0), 
 (('consumer0', 'consumer11', 0), 0), 
 (('consumer0', 'consumer2', 0), 0), 
 (('consumer0', 'consumer20', 0), 0), 
 (('consumer0', 'consumer3', 0), 0),
 ...]
```

How can I sort the list and get result like

```
[(('consumer0', 'consumer0', 0), 0), 
 (('consumer0', 'consumer1', 0), 0), 
 (('consumer0', 'consumer2', 0), 0), 
 (('consumer0', 'consumer3', 0), 0), 
 (('consumer0', 'consumer4', 0), 0),
 ...
 (('consumer0', 'consumer10', 0), 0), 
 (('consumer0', 'consumer11', 0), 0)
 ...
]
```

Comment: If the strings are of fixed length, you can try `sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[0][2], int(x[0][0][8:]), int(x[0][1][8:])))`. Otherwise, I would recommend `re` to extract digits

Comment: sort the agents list direct after the initial declaration `agents = ["consumer{0}".format(i_s) for i_s in sorted([int(o.replace("consumer", "")) for o in agents])]` and remove the line `P_nm = [(k,v) for k,v in P_nm.items()]`, i think is more readable since you don't have any indexing

Comment: You should zero pad your consumer numbers (e.g. consumer09) to ensure that they sort as you would expect

Comment: Thank you so much Chris! It suits this case perfectly , it works!

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [`natsort`](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort) that does exactly what you want. It does something similar to what [@Chris's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61136643/how-to-sort-alphanumeric-strings-in-numpy-matrix-and-list-in-python#comment108157157_61136643) suggests, but in a more general way, and covers many more [corner cases](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/howitworks.html#special-cases-everywhere).

`natsort` is available in anaconda and PyPi, so `conda install natsort` and `pip install natsort` should both work.

To use it, start with the [`natsorted`](https://natsort.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#natsort.natsorted) function, similar to the built-in [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), but with the functionality you want.

```
mylist = [
    (('consumer0', 'consumer0', 0), 0), 
    (('consumer0', 'consumer1', 0), 0), 
    (('consumer0', 'consumer10', 0), 0), 
    (('consumer0', 'consumer11', 0), 0), 
    (('consumer0', 'consumer2', 0), 0), 
    (('consumer0', 'consumer20', 0), 0), 
    (('consumer0', 'consumer3', 0), 0),
    ...
]
mylist = natsorted(mylist, key=lambda item: item[0][:2])
```

Since `natsort` is pretty smart about unpacking the structure of elements, your case can be reduced to just

```
mylist = natsorted(mylist)
```

Since this may come up, I am not the author of natsort ([this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1399279/sethmmorton) is). Just a happy user.